# Add text and arrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, text

I'm using overleaf and I have to plot 2 square, as done with the code below. I'm not able to do the following:

- put the two squares in the center of the pages. I try with `\begin{center}` and `\begin{figure} \centering` but it doesn't work;
- add the text "A" in the middle of the white section of the first square and add an arrow under the second square with letters B and C at the beginning and at the end of the arrow.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Nodes
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\fill[black] (2,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\columnbreak
\columnbreak
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Nodes
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\shade[left color=white,right color=black] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using columns to try to position your tikzpictures besides each other, you could draw them in a single tikzpicture and use the `scope` environment to shift one of them to the right:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Nodes
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\fill[black] (2,0) rectangle (4,4);
\node[red,font=\bfseries\Huge] at (1,2) {A};

\begin{scope}[xshift=.5\textwidth]
%Nodes
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\shade[left color=white,right color=black] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\node (B) at (0,-0.5) {B};
\node (C) at (4,-0.5) {C};
\draw[->] (B) -- (C) ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With two `tikzpicture`s, rectangles replaced by nodes and displaced by `\hfil`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
node distance = 0pt,
     N/.style = {draw, fill=#1, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=4cm, font=\Large}
                    ]
\node (n1) [N=white] {A};
\node (n2) [N=black, right=of n1] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfil
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
node distance = 0pt]
\node (n1) [draw, minimum size=4cm, 
            left color=white,right color=black] {};
\node (a)  [below=of n1.south west] {B};
\node (b)  [below=of n1.south east] {C};
\draw[-Straight Barb]   (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]